# Flexislider Vimeo Resizing Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vimeo

I would like to use Flexislider for different Vimeo videos. This seems to work fine for the first and the third video. The second video, however, is not shown properly. There is a margin on top and the Flexislider resizes. The videos have all the same size. Any ideas?

You find my test setup here: http://pinkstinks.jacobfricke.me

Answer (score 0):

I just had a quick look at your source code and found your problem.
Your first and third video are wrapped with a div.fluid-width-video-wrapper and then inside a

tag, while your second video is wrapped directly with a div and the

tag sit under it so you get an extra line.
Try remove all the

tags around your video, I don't see any point having them. Besides, you have non-break space on the top too which can also be deleted. The " " thing. That just gives you space, why do that?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I always tend to forget that Wordpress still adds some things to HTML view.

Comment: weird some of my words are missing in the answer. The extra tag around your video is p, and the extra non-break space is & n b s p, hope this shows up. And if it works for you I hope you can make this as an answer :)